# Aws lambda access cognito identity (trough api gateway websocket api) in route

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am creating a websocket API Gateway and I have the following routes:

$connect which uses AWS_IAM authorization (Signature Version 4)

$disconnect

$default

sendmessage

The problem I have is the following, in the connect lambda the RequestContext.Identity have all the properties valid (fields like cognito identity id), but when I invoke sendmessage through the websocket only the RequestContext.Identity.SourceIp and RequestContext.Identity.UserAgent are filled, is there any way to get CognitoIdentityId in the sendmessage route?

$connect RequestContext.Identity is

```
"CognitoIdentityPoolId": "eu-central-1:a520283f-1353-43d7-b441-b0fc5152b027",
"AccountId": "396151468972",
"CognitoIdentityId": "eu-central-1:1a9421b5-3361-4da9-8adf-22cf5d92eeb9",
"Caller": "AROAVYPDXWOWIJFD6FIYE:CognitoIdentityCredentials",
"ApiKey": null,
"SourceIp": "1.15.1.22",//modified
"CognitoAuthenticationType": "authenticated",
"CognitoAuthenticationProvider": "cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_gPSLBBoLn,cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_gPSLBBoLn:CognitoSignIn:7812ef00-44cd-4c3c-a8f7-df2434441e67",
"UserArn": "arn:aws:sts::396151468972:assumed-role/Cognito_NanoVoltsAuth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials",
"UserAgent": "BestHTTP 1.12.3",
"User": "AROAVYPDXWOWIJFD6FIYE:CognitoIdentityCredentials"
```

sendmessage RequestContext.Identity is

```
"CognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
"AccountId": null,
"CognitoIdentityId": null,
"Caller": null,
"ApiKey": null,
"SourceIp": "1.15.1.22",//modified
"CognitoAuthenticationType": null,
"CognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
"UserArn": null,
"UserAgent": "BestHTTP 1.12.3",
"User": null
```

Comment: How did you manage to pass the information in the first connection request? Despite AWS_IAM auth, a web socket in my case is created for me without authorization information. Possible on the second call identity information missing due to the fact that the authorization occurs only on the connect stage. https://medium.com/@lancers/using-custom-authorizer-for-websocket-apis-on-api-gateway-95abb517acab